# Laravel 5.5 Human resource App

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Good day people

I am creating a Laravel project which is an Human resource application I got stuck by where I need to calculate the leaves, meaning I have two table one which I am assigning employees leaves days and other table which I am store the leaves request, so I need to update the leaves assigned day by deducting from it taken days

THIS IS MY JS FILE

```js
var baseUrl = $("#base_url").val();
var currentLeave = 0;
var currentUnit ="";
var currentEmp =0;
var currentUsed=0;


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start_date").datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    })

    $("#end_date").datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    })
    $('#example').DataTable({
        buttons: [
            {
                 extend: 'print',className: "btn btn-default btn-sm btn-success",
                title: window.reportTitle,
            },
            {
               extend: 'excelHtml5',className: "btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary",
                title: 'Leave Report',
            }
        ],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        responsive: true,
        "bSort": false,
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        destroy: true,
        searching: !0
    });
    
      $('#data1').DataTable({
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',className: "btn btn-default btn-sm btn-success",
                title: window.reportTitle,
            },
            {
               extend: 'excelHtml5',className: "btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary",
                title: 'Leave Report',
            }
        ],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        responsive: true,
        "bSort": false,
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        destroy: true,
        searching: !0
    });
});


function approveLeave(id,unit,emp_id,used_leave) {
    $("#approveModal").modal('toggle');
    currentLeave = id;
    currentUnit= unit;
    currentEmp= emp_id;
    currentUsed = used_leave;
    
}

function approveNow() {
    var startDate = $("#start_date").val();
    var endDate = $("#end_date").val();
   
    if (startDate != "" && endDate != "") {
        if (startDate < endDate) {
            var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

            $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + "/approve-leave",
                method: "POST",
                data: {id:currentLeave, _token: csrf_token, status: 'Approved', start_date: startDate,unit:currentUnit,emp_id:currentEmp,used_leave:currentUsed,return_date: endDate},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == "success") {
                        swal({
                            title: 'Success!',
                            text: 'Data has been updated',
                            type: 'success'
                        })
                        window.location.reload();
                    } else {
                        swal({
                            title: 'Failled',
                            text: data.err_msg,
                            type: 'error'
                        })
                    }
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                error: function () {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: 'Something went wrong!',
                        type: 'error'
                    })
                }
            });
        } else {
            swal({
                title: 'Failed',
                text: 'Start Date should less than End Date',
                type: 'error'
            })
        }
    } else {
        swal({
            title: 'Failed',
            text: 'Start date and end date required',
            type: 'error'
        })
    }

}

function rejectLeave(id) {
    var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    swal({
        title: 'Enter rejection reason',
        input: 'textarea',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Reject',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
        buttonsStyling: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        inputPlaceholder: 'This rejection will be sent via email to the Employee',
        preConfirm: function (textarea) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                if (textarea == "") {
                    reject("Enter a comment for rejection");
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "reject-leave",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {id: id, _token: csrf_token, comment: textarea, status: 'Rejected'},
                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data.status == "success") {

                                swal({
                                    title: 'Success!',
                                    text: 'you have rejected this employee!',
                                    type: 'success'
                                })
                            } else {
                                swal({
                                    title: 'Oops...',
                                    text: data.err_msg,
                                    type: 'error'
                                })
                            }
                            window.location.reload();
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            swal({
                                title: 'Oops...',
                                text: 'Something went wrong, please try again later!',
                                type: 'error'
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }).then(function () {
    });
}
```

MY FUNCTION IN CONTROLLER

```html
  public function approvedLeave(Request $request) {
        
        $results1 = DB::select("SELECT SUM(numberof_day - used_leave) AS diff  from assign_leave WHERE emp_id=?",[$request->get("emp_id")]);
        $requestedDays = 0;
        if ($results1[0]->diff > 0) {
            if ($request->get('unit') == "Hours") {
                if ($request->get("start_date") == $request->get("return_date")) {
                    $requestedDays = 0.5;
                } else {
                    $fdate = $request->get("start_date");
                    $tdate = $request->get("return_date");
                    $datetime1 = new \DateTime($fdate);
                    $datetime2 = new \DateTime($tdate);
                    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                    $days = $interval->format('%a');
                    $requestedDays = $days - 0.5;
                  
                }
            } else {
                $fdate = $request->get("start_date");
                $tdate = $request->get("return_date");
                $datetime1 = new \DateTime($fdate);
                $datetime2 = new \DateTime($tdate);
                $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                $requestedDays = $interval->format('%a');
               
            }
            if ($requestedDays < $results1[0]->diff) {
                $results = DB::update("UPDATE leaves SET status=?, start_date=?, return_date=? WHERE id = ?", [$request->get("status"), $request->get("start_date"), $request->get("return_date"), $request->get("id")]);
                $results1 = DB::update("UPDATE assign_leave SET numberof_day=? , used_leave = used_leave+? WHERE emp_id = ?", [$request->get("used_leave"),$request->get("numberof_day"),$request->get("emp_id")]);
              //  dd($request->get("used_leave"), $request->get("assign_id"));
                if ($results) {
                    //$leave = Leave::find($request->get("id"));
                    return response()->json(["status" => "success"]);
                } else {
                    return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "err_msg" => "update failed please try gain"]);
                }
            } else {
                return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "err_msg" => "request days is more the remaining days"]); 
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "err_msg" => "you do not have enough available days "]);
        }
    }
```

MY BLADE.PHP

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-warning">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#pill1" data-toggle="tab">New Leave Request</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#pill2" data-toggle="tab">Approved&Rejected</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="col-md-10 row">
                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" 
                            data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add Leave Types</button>
                    <a href="{{url('/assignleave')}}" type="button" rel="tooltip" title="assign Leave" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple pull-right btn-sm">
                        Assign Leave
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="pill1">
                        <table class="table"  id="example" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>FirstName</th>
                                    <th>Leave-Type</th>
                                    <th>Start-Date</th>
                                    <th>End-Date</th>
                                    <th>Expected Return</th>
                                    <th>Approved Date </th>
                                    <th>Comment</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($all_leaves as $index =>$leave)
                                @if($leave->status == "Pending")
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$leave->First_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->leave_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->start_date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->return_date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->expected_start_date}} </td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->date_approved}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->comment}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->status}} </td>
                                    <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                        <button type="button"  onclick="approveLeave('{{$leave->id}}','{{$leave->unit}}','{{$leave->emp_id}}')"  rel="tooltip" title="Approved" class="btn btn-primary btn-simple btn-xs">
                                            Approve
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button" onclick="rejectLeave('{{$leave->id}}' )"  rel="tooltip" title="Rejected" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
                                            Reject
                                        </button>                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>             
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="pill2">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%" id="data1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email </th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Start-Date</th>
                                    <th>End-Date</th>
                                    <th>Expected </th>
                                    <th>Approved Date </th>
                                    <th>Status</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($all_leaves as $index =>$leave)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$leave->First_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->email_address}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->leave_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->start_date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->return_date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->expected_start_date}} </td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->date_approved}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->status}} </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="pill4">
                        <table class="table" id="datas">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Name1</th>
                                    <th>Email </th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Start Date</th>
                                    <th>Returned Date</th>
                                    <th>Date Approved</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($all_leaves as $index =>$leave)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{$leave->id}}" name="selected_employee[]" onchange="showOrHideBulkButton(this)">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->First_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->email_address}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->leave_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->start_date}} </td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->return_date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->date_approved}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$leave->status}} </td>

                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="pill3">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end col-md-12 -->
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id=rejectModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="enter comment for rejection" id="comment"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button"  data-loading-text="Processing..." class="btn btn-success">Reject</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade " id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
        <div class="modal-content " >
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Leave Types</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 control-label">Leave Type</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" name="leave_name" value="" required autofocus>
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lastname" class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="" required>
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label  class="col-md-4 control-label">No of Days</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" name="no_of_days" value="" required>
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="approveModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="enter leave start date" id="start_date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="enter leave end date" id="end_date">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="approveNow()" data-loading-text="Processing..." class="btn btn-success">Approve</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@section('footer_scripts')
<script src="{{url('/js/leave_management.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please try to make a [mcve] to get help with your code, btw. you did not say anything about what your problem is...

Comment: hi the problem i cant be able to update the assign_leave table but incrementing the Taken-days ,and decrement numberof_days, the code is running and its successfull but does update

Comment: from the function

Comment: $results2 = DB::update("UPDATE assign_leave SET numberof_day=?, used_leave = used_leave+? WHERE emp_id = ?", [$request->get("used_leave"), $request->get("numberof_day"), $request->get("emp_id")]);

Comment: Please put that additional information in your question with an [edit]. I can't help you with your thematic, but I can help you to make a good question which is worth to be answered :)